# Symbol vector could not be resolved

Tags: c++, class, vector

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;


class block{
public:
    long nx,ny;
    vector<long> s;
    block(long &x, long &y):nx(x),ny(y),vector<long> s((x+1)*(y+1),0) {}
};

int main() {
    block B(2,2);
    for(int i=1;i<=9;i++) {
        cout<<B.s(i);
    }

    cout << "!!!Hello World!!!" << endl; // prints !!!Hello World!!!
    return 0;
}
```

Compiled and error message shows that symbol "vector" could not be resolved. What is the mistake? I want to define a class which contain a variable dimension vector to initialize.

---

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;


class block{
public:
    long nx,ny;
    vector<long> s;
    block(long &x, long &y):nx(x),ny(y),s((x+1)*(y+1),0) {}
};

int main() {
    block B(2,2);
    for(int i=0;i<=9;i++) {
        cout<<B.s[i];
    }

    cout << "!!!Hello World!!!" << endl; // prints !!!Hello World!!!
    return 0;
}
```

still got problem at block B(2,2); error message:no instance of constructor "block::block" matches the argument list

why? thanks!

Comment: Array indices are zero-based, and you can leave out the `,0` when initializing the vector, as it does that anyway.

Answer (score 4):

Firstly:

```
  vector<long> s((x+1)*(y+1),0)
```

should be:

```
  s((x+1)*(y+1),0)
```

should not repeat the type for `s`.
Meanwhile the constructor should be:

```
  block(const long &x, const long &y):
    nx(x), ny(y), s((x + 1) * (y + 1), 0)
  {
  }
```

if you really need reference. Since otherwise, when you do

```
 block B(2,2);
```

inside `main`, it will give you error because constructor takes `long&`, you are passing int constants. Deep reason about this is related to lvalue and rvalues:  integer constants are rvalues, however, `long&` is reference to non-const long, which is lvalue reference. According to this blog: [lvalues, rvalues and references](http://akrzemi1.wordpress.com/2011/11/09/lvalues-rvalues-and-references/)

> An lvalue reference (to non-const type) is a reference that can be initialized with an lvalue. Well, only with those lvalues that do not render const or volatile types. An rvalue reference (to non-const type) is a reference that can be initialized with an rvalue (again, only with those rvalues that do not designate const or volatile types). An lvalue reference to const type is a reference that can be initialized with rvalues and lvalues alike (rendering constant and non-constant types).

Further, according to C++11 standard: Section 4.1 standard conversions:

> Standard conversions are implicit conversions defined for built-in types. A standard conversion sequence is a sequence of standard conversions in the following
>   order:
>
> — Zero or one conversion from the following set: lvalue-to-rvalue conversion, array-to-pointer conversion,
>   and function-to-pointer conversion.
>
> — Zero or one conversion from the following set: integral promotions, floating point promotion, integral
>   conversions, floating point conversions, floating-integral conversions, pointer conversions, pointer to
>   member conversions, and boolean conversions.
>
> — Zero or one qualification conversion.

There is no rvalue-to-lvalue conversion. This is why you saw that compile error. Adding `const` before `long&`make it be able to be initialized with rvalues, that's why the error goes away after the change.

Secondly,

```
  cout<<B.s(i);
```

should be:

```
cout<<B.s[i];
```

You should use `[]` to access vector elements.

Thirdly, vector index starts from `0`, so

```
for(int i=1;i<=9;i++)
```

should be

```
for(int i=0;i<9;i++)
```

Otherwise, index out of bounds. See a working example here: http://ideone.com/YLT3mG

Comment: Thanks, made changes of you guys mentioned, but still got problem at the statement: block s(2,2); error message is : no instance of constructor "block::block" matches the argument list

Comment: @northfly I added more information to explain why you saw the compiler error, hope that these helps.

Answer (score 3):

```
block(long &x, long &y):nx(x),ny(y),vector<long> s((x+1)*(y+1),0) {}
```

Don't repeat `vector<long>` in the initialization list. There's also no reason to pass in references, so delete the ampersands.

```
block(long x, long y):
    nx(x), ny(y), s((x + 1) * (y + 1), 0)
{
}
```

Comment: And constructor requires lvalues(can't understand why), while rvalues was passed.